# Saving multiple PFObjects from an array at once

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to set multiple objects at one time from an array into Parses database, although all that happens is it just sets one of the objects not all of them. Not sure where I am going wrong, code:

```
var user2 = [PFUser]() //array of PFUsers.

 let addRoomObject = PFObject(className: "Room")
                for user in user2 {
                    println(user) //prints two multiple objects
                    addRoomObject["user1"] = PFUser.currentUser()
                    addRoomObject["user2"] = user
                    addRoomObject.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                    if success == true {
                        println("Added new users to room")
                        } 
                    })
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`PFObject.saveAllInBackground(array, block: {
        (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        // you code here
    })` instead.

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks but how would I write it in relation to what I have already written, what exactly goes in the `array`???

Comment: Also it is saying `PFObject' does not have a member named 'saveAllInBackground`???

Comment: This is a little late but adding for reference. Array is where you'll put your array of PFObjects. Also, PFObject.saveAll should be what you're looking for.